# Creating new file based on web scrape then downloading to client's browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, streamwriter

I am creating a website in Asp.Net and using it to scrape another webpage. My goal is to create a new file with the links of the scraped page. I am able to scrape the page successfully and print the text to a label on the page, however I cannot seem to get the page to write the data to a new text file and download the new file with all of the links. Currently I'm using StreamWriter in the following way:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Urllist.txt");
Response.Clear();
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, 
Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Write(links); 
    //links is the string of the scraped URL's I want on the text file
}
Response.End();
```

Currently this only writes the first line to the new text file.

How do I get all of the URL's from the links string to print on the new text file? If possible I don't want to do anything with the local machine or having to use a local file path, and just have the site write the new file with the proper contents to the user's downloads.

Code used for memorystream is the following:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
foreach(var lk in linkLines)
{
    var prt = lk + "\r\n";
    tw.WriteLine(prt);
}
tw.Flush();
var bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Urllist.txt");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

But this code provides only the first link and then for some reason also includes the HTML from the web page doing the scraping.

Please Help!!

Comment: Is `links` a list or a string? it is only writing one line because you are only writing once. Maybe loop through all the links?

Comment: If you want to return a downloaded file, just create a file in memory and then return that from your controller

Comment: I have tried writing to memorystream and using a textwriter and then looping through the results to try and print each entry, but now I am getting a text document with the first entry in the list and all of the HTML contents of the page and I'm not sure how.

Comment: Can you post that code? Not sure where that is coming from based on the code snippet that is there now

Comment: @ivcubr How do you know there's a controller? How do you know this isn't Web Forms, or a generic ASP.NET handler?

Comment: @mason Sorry, I dont. Was just assuming

Comment: debug debug debug your code step by step...

Comment: @ivcubr I have edited my answer to include the memory stream code.
I also am not using a controller for this